# How to decode q-encoding in C?

Tags: c, encoding, decoding

Is there any library for q-encoding? I need to decode some q-encoded text, such as:

```
**Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?=A1Hola,_se=F1or!?=**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GNU Mailutils libmailutils](http://mailutils.org/) is one example of such library.

"Q"-encoding is specified by [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) so using it as a search term gives you other relevant results.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Q-encoding libraries, couldn't find any.

Do note, though, that your latter example does not look like Q encoding, notice that the character after the charset ("UTF-8") is not a 'Q' but a 'B'. This means it's base64 encoding, for which there are plenty of libraries, [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Base64-Encoding.html) is one example.

See [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word) on Wikipedia for details on how to detect which encoding is being used.

Answer (score 1):

Email subject is encoded according to RFC 2047. We can decode it by using function `mu_rfc2047_decode()` provided by GNU mailutils.
Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mailutils/mailutils.h>
#include <mailutils/mime.h>
...
char cipher[] = "=?GB2312?B?UmWjujEy1MK8xruuse0=?=";
char *plaintext;
int rc = mu_rfc2047_decode("utf-8", cipher, &plaintext);
if (rc) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Fail to decode '%s'\n", cipher);
} else {
    puts(plaintext); 
    free(plaintext);
}
```

To download GNU mailutils, visit https://mailutils.org/

To understand RFC 2047, read https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt

Test Result:

```
Cipher:
**Subject: =?iso-8859-1?Q?=A1Hola,_se=F1or!?=**
Plaintext:
**Subject: ¡Hola, señor!**

Cipher:
=?Big5?Q?=AE=F8=B6O=BA=A18=A4d=BFW=AEa?=
Plaintext:
消費滿8千獨家

Cipher:
=?GB2312?B?UmWjujEy1MK8xruuse0=?=
Plaintext:
Re：12月计划表
```