# How to decode windows-874 imap subject?

Tags: imap, decode, subject

I'm having a serious problem with imap decoding. I received an email which might be encoded in windows-874. And this causes the whole letter to be read. I tried to use `iconv('tis-620','utf-8',$txt)` but I've had no luck.

I've tried searching everywhere that there might be an answer but it seems like it is the first problem of the universe. (or I don't search the correct word?)

The subject is :

Charset : ASCII

> =?windows-874?Q?=CB=E9=CD=A7=BE=D1=A1=C3=D2=A4=D2=BE=D4=E0=C8=C9=CA=D3=CB=C3=D1=BA=A7=D2=B9=E4=B7=C2=E0=B7=D5=E8=C2=C7=E4=B7=C2=A4=C3=D1=E9=A7=B7=D5=E8
>   30
>   =E2=C3=A7=E1=C3=C1=CA=C7=D1=CA=B4=D5=CA=D8=A2=D8=C1=C7=D4=B7=AB=CD=C2 8?=

So, please tell me what the encoding is, if it's not tis-62. How can I decode this into a human language?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701269/how-to-decode-q-encoding-in-c).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but not work!

Comment: How did it not work?  What did you do?  'It did not work' is not enough information for us to help you.  This is RFC 2047 encoding.

Comment: @Max Didn't I say it clear above?

Comment: My mail parser/decoder turns that into "ห้องพักราคาพิเศษสำหรับงานไทยเที่ยวไทยครั้งที่ 30 โรงแรมสวัสดีสุขุมวิทซอย 8", which google translates as "Rates for Thailand Travel Thailand 30 times Sawasdee Sukhumvit Soi 8". Hm. Is that plausible? I've no idea.

Comment: @arnt Would you mind showing me the code sample? So I can learn how to make it so simple.

Comment: It involves a few thousand lines of code. There's an RFC2047 decoder, then a charset guesser and conversion to unicode. (I know it says cp874. Sometimes you can trust what that says and sometimes you cannot.)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my way home. Firstly I created a function to detect any encoding in a text given.

```
function win874($str){
    $win874=strpos($str,"windows-874");
    return $win874;
}

function utf8($str){
    $utf8=strpos($str,"UTF-8");
    return $utf8;
}
```

Then I convert with php functions:

```
if(win874($headers->subject)=="0" and utf8($headers->subject)=="0"){
    echo $headers->subject;
}
if(win874($headers->subject)>="1"){
    $subj0=explode("?",$headers->subject);
    echo $subj0[3];
}
if(utf8($headers->subject)>="1"){
    echo imap_utf8($headers->subject);
}
```

Because text with windows-874 always begins with **"=?windows-874?Q?"** so I used the simple function like "explode()" to extract the main idea from the junk. As I said, the main idea always comes after the 3rd question mark. Then I have the subject.

But the problem remains. I still have to change the browser encoding to Thai to make the text readable. (settings>tools>encoding>Thai : in chrome). Any suggestions?

Comment: Er, generally you use a generic RFC 2407 decoder, which I'm sure your language has somewhere to get a unicode representation of it, then you output it using whatever character set your page is using (presumably utf-8).